# Implications of kernel size on the median filter?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

What are the direct implications of the kernel size when applying the median filter?

What would change in the case of a `3 X 3 kernel size`, `5 X 5 kernel size` or `9 X 9 kernel size`

Comment: Mostly you're going to see it in the execution time. There aren't a lot of ways to optimize a median filter.

Comment: @MarkRansom not true: histograms!

Answer (score 2):

It depends somewhat on the shape of the filter aperture (normally square or circular), but basically features in the image smaller than the aperture size will be filtered out, while retaining relatively sharp edges between features in the image larger than the aperture size.

Corners, unlike edges, are not well-preserved by the median filter, and tend to be blurred to a degree proportional to the size of the median filter.